# Looking for a framework class that allows one writer and rejects other writers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I am aware of the [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) classes and I'm looking for something similar and I hope that there's a .NET framework class already, so I don't need to bother implementing my own.

Here's what I'm looking for:

- one writer can enter the "lock"
- one more writer can wait in a queue if the "lock" is owned
- any more writers just return or get an exception that the operation is currently not possible

Does such a class exist in the .NET framework?

What I want to achieve: there are incoming triggers at a very high rate. On each trigger I want to save state information (bullet point 1). The data is not too important, so I don't really care about some items getting lost (bullet point 3).

However, I want to ensure that I capture at least one state which was triggered while I was saving data, because it could contain an important change. That makes up bullet point 2. I know that there's no guarantee that I will be able to capture that state change, because it could have been changed forth and back multiple times. That's acceptable. At least I want to try...

Comment: What about readers? Who is acquiring the reader locks, and how is it related to the writers?

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. Why can the "one state which was triggered while I was saving" be important if the data isn't important? What if the important state is nbr. 2 while you are saving, the first you want to discard?

Comment: @Luaan: actually there are no readers on the machine where the writers are.

Comment: Why are you using a `ReaderWriterLock`, then? That's what a semaphore is for :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: hmm, I see ... consider a traffic light. A car arrives. The car is detected almost simultaneously by radar, infrared, ultrasonic, magnetic and picture comparison. Now, a state is saved: 3D model of the car, pictures, etc. This may take a minute. The traffic light becomes green but the process has not finished yet. The car drives away. Again, many incoming triggers. Saving the state completes. If all writers are discarded, the new "empty" state without the car will not be captured. Does it make sense?

Comment: That sounds awfully dangerous. Are you sure you don't want two entirely separate mechanisms to record the two very different things? Why would you want to rely on queuing two pretty much random requests, instead of keeping them separate?

Comment: @Luaan: I didn't say I am using it. I am aware of it but I think it doesn't suit my needs. Therefore I'm asking.

Comment: Multi-threading is hard. Really hard. I find it a bit... unsettling, that you would know about `ReaderWriterLock` *before* you learned about synchronization *primitives*, like the semaphore. Are you sure you can write multi-threaded code safely? A good primer on multi-threading is http://www.albahari.com/threading/, I highly recommend at the very least going through that, carefully, before you attempt any multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only need writers, the simplest solution would be to use a [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx). If you also need to allow readers, you're in a bit of a pickle.

The basic approach might look something like this:

```
SemaphoreSlim _writerSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2);
readonly object _actionLock = new object();

public bool TryExecute()
{
  bool acquired = false;
  try
  {
    acquired = _writerSemaphore.Wait(0);

    if (!acquired) return false;

    lock (_actionLock)
    {
      // Your action
    }

    return true;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (acquired) _writerSemaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

If you also want readers after all, the easiest solution is to make sure that the queue is *before* the ReaderWriterLock:

```
SemaphoreSlim _writerSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2);
ReaderWriterLockSlim _readerWriterLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public bool TryExecuteWriter(Action action)
{
  bool acquired = false;
  try
  {
    acquired = _writerSemaphore.Wait(0);

    if (!acquired) return false;

    _readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
      action();

      return true;
    }
    finally
    {
      _readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (acquired) _writerSemaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

This will ensure that at any time, there are at most two threads waiting to enter the write lock. In the interest of correctness, note that there is a slight race-condition between releasing the writer lock and releasing the semaphore - however, given your constraints, this shouldn't be an issue.